# Magic Mouse - Scroll Area

Tags: mouse

I would like to reduce the scroll surface area on my Magic Mouse. I tend to engage the scroll just by resting my index or middle finger on the surface. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free third party app called Magic Prefs which allows you to adjust the scroll area and a bunch of other things

http://magicprefs.com/